# App does not print information to the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

EDIT: Updated question 1 for more clarity.

So, this might be a stupid question, but here we go.

A few months ago, during classes we wrote a simple weather app, with the intent to further develop it.

My questions are:

1. Where and how the function should be called/invoked?
2. How to execute the code, so that the App prints the information received from the two APIs, in the console.
3. Once the information is printed, how it can be manipulated in the front end, like displaying on a simple card?

Here is the main code:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
import {
    TimeStampToWeekDay,
    TimeStampToHoursMinutes
} from '../utils/dateHelpers';


const weatherAPIKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY
const weatherAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});

const locationAPIKey = process.env.LOCATION_API_KEY
const locationAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});


export const getDailyWeatherByCountry = async ({city, country}, success, failure) => {
    const {data: locData} = await locationAPI.get(`json?q=${country}, ${city}&key=${locationAPIKey}`);
    const {lat, lng} = locData.results[0].geometry;
    const {data: weatherData} = await weatherAPI.get(`onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&units=metric&exclude=hourly,alerts,current,minutely&appid=${weatherAPIKey}`)
    console.log(weatherData.daily);
    const formatedDays = weatherData.daily.map(({temp, clouds, dt, sunrise, sunset, wind_deg, wind_speed}) => ({
        temp: temp.day,
        cloudLevel: clouds,
        weekDay: TimeStampToWeekDay(dt),
        sunrise: TimeStampToHoursMinutes(sunrise),
        sunset: TimeStampToHoursMinutes(sunset),
        windDeg: wind_deg,
        windSpeed: wind_speed
    }))
    console.log(weatherData.daily[0])
    console.log(formatedDays[0])    
}
```

And here is also the date helpers code(if needed):

```
    const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tueday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
export const TimeStampToWeekDay = (timestamp) =>{
    return days[new Date(timestamp * 1000).getDay()];
}

export const TimeStampToHoursMinutes = (timestamp) => {
    const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    return `${date.getHours()}: ${date.getMinutes()}`;
}
```

I have also the whole project uploaded on GitHub, if that makes it easier to analyze it.

[Github link](https://github.com/mrvanagas/108-weather-api)

Comment: *"How does it work?"*. That is far too broad a question. If you are uncertain about something it is incumbent on you to explain what it is specifically you need help understanding by referencing parts of the code and including what you do understand as well. SO isn't a free tutorial service. See : [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: executing part is a little tricky here, cause I'm not sure if you even tried to run `npm run start`. If yes then maybe you are missing the env file with API keys (not `.env.example` but `.env`). If this also not works maybe you are using the component wrong cause you are importing the whole api folder but use in code (template part) `App` only (you should use `getDailyWeatherByCountry` probably but maybe someone more skilleed in react will add few cents

Comment: I don't think you are actually calling `getDailyWeatherByCountry` function from anywhere.

Comment: also always try to add information about what you already tried to do (for example tried running, tried changing file name etc.) this greatly helps people that try to help you

Comment: @JacckMark Yes, I ran the npm run start, the .env with API keys are all set up. My issue, is that when we wrote this code and ran it, the information was printed in the browser console. What I am confused with are the variable entry: in line 22 of the main code, there are ${country} and ${city}, in where the location variables should be written in.  So, rephrasing my question: where should those variables be written in?

Comment: these are props https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html you add them like this <mycomponent city={yourcity} /> when using the component (but as stated by @PriyankKachhela you don't use the component nowhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the feelings of charlietfl in the comments, but I also want to help, so here we go.

1. In your App.jsx, you should add a `componentDidMount` method. This method will be called whenever your component is mounted in the DOM (see point 2 for more information). In this method, you can call your `getDailyWeatherByCountry`, and it will successfully console.log().

2. Take a look at the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method of React since you do it the old way.
3. You can use frameworks like MaterialUI in your App.jsx to display things, or go the old HTML way directly.

I'll update my answer as you give more details.